# Reduce the amount of RAM used by MySQL

Tags: mysql, memory

I have recently purchased a 1GB DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 VPS and it is running a blog written in Python and Django.

I have installed NGINX and MySQL on the same machine.

My problem is that MySQL is consuming a lot of RAM, which is causing the system to crash. I know it's because of low RAM, but for now I want to continue with these configurations.

I read many posts about optimizing MySQL to use less memory, or about increasing the swap space.

I am using InnoDB storage engine.

Can you suggest what options I have or how I can reduce the amount of RAM used by MySQL .

Here is the screenshot of `htop` on the server:

[image: Htop snapshot]

Comment: "I read many posts about optimizing mysql to use low memory, or increasing the swap space." what of those posts have you tried?

Comment: there are many posts on google. its making a confusion only. i just want to know that can i reduce the amount of ram used by mysql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage

Answer (score -2):

1. Edit the `my.cnf` file and specify the amount of RAM MySQL is allowed to use
2. Change the ib_data file to ensure that all databases create their own file. That way reading the database does not take as much RAM

All these edits should be done in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.